# Regex to find words in order but in between other words

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a problem implementing a regex for a particular scenario.

Lets say the input is "the brown dog" to be searched from "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". It should return true with the following conditions:

1. -not case sensitive
2. -must be in order (1st word is 'the', 2nd is 'brown', 3rd is 'dog').

This means inputs like "the dog brown", "fox brown", "the quick fox brown" would return false but "the dog", "quick brown", "jumps over the" return true. I hope i provided enough samples.

So far my regex `"(?i)(?:\\S+\\s)?\\S*"+targetString+"\\S*(?:\\s\\S+)?"` only works for exact strings but not in between other words.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
String reg = "";
for(String s:targetString.split(' '))
   reg+= s + "(\\s|\\S)*";
//Compile reg as regex and match using pattern
```

look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/mM0hY6/2)

Comment: Why `"(\\s|\\S)*"`? This will cause backtracking issues.

Comment: @stribizhev I am sorry I didn't get that.. can you explain what are you trying to say?

Comment: Just that to match any character, you need to use `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier and `.*` subpattern.

Comment: @stribizhev there can be other solution :P...recursively split the `testString` on the term basis and search the array from `1 to N` for 2nd term and so on until you find the match for the last term :P it'll be a havoc for the cpu though..

Comment: @stribizhev well I guess the java compiler would take care of that optimization when compiling the regex.. I just tried to provide a quick solution.. but there can be others as well..

Comment: @ReubenJaMesAvenoGruta did you find any other answer to this